# Twitter API - Search tweets without t.co rewritten links

Tags: php, api, search, twitter, twitter-oauth

I’m doing research for college, where I need to do searches using the twitter API using the word “twitter” and some other keywords, to do some analysis. I did a simple application in php that returned me 1000 tweets from the word sought . However, the twitter API returns me tweets without the word ” twitter ” , I think this happens because the URLs ( links or images) of tweets that are replaced by “t.co” links.

My search code

```
   <?php
    require_once 'twitteroauth.php';

    define('CONSUMER_KEY', 'aaaaaaaaa');
    define('CONSUMER_SECRET', 'bbbbbbbbb');
    define('ACCESS_TOKEN', 'cccccccccc');
    define('ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET', 'ddddddddddddd');

    function search(array $query)
    {
      $toa = new TwitterOAuth(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET, ACCESS_TOKEN, ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET);
      return $toa->get('search/tweets', $query);
    }

    $max_id = "";
    foreach (range(1, 10) as $i) {
    $query = array(
      "q" => $_POST['search'],
      "count" => 100,
      "result_type" => "mixed",
      "max_id" => $max_id,
    );

    $results = search($query);
    $a= $results->statuses;
    foreach ($a as $result) {
       echo $result->text .'<br>';
       $max_id = $result->id_str;
    }
    }

    die;
```